# React project error for naming the folder

Tags: reactjs, directory, antd

I have a React project using functional components with React v18, antd, and Redux + Redux Thunk for state management along with other front-end related libraries like React Router DOM, etc.at first I yarn installed the project and When I ran yarn start, I received the following error:

src\modules\addBooking\detailPlanning.js
Line 73:7:   Must use destructuring form assignment  react/destructuring-assignment
Line 76:28:  Must use destructuring form assignment  react/destructuring-assignment

or

src\modules\managePayRates\payrateHistory\payrateHistory.js
Line 98:23:   Unknown property 'level' found  react/no-unknown-property
Line 101:23:  Unknown property 'level' found  react/no-unknown-property
Line 104:23:  Unknown property 'level' found  react/no-unknown-property

I tried resolving the issue by fixing the destructuring form assignment in the mentioned lines or removing the level properties on those components, but the error persisted. Surprisingly, when I copied the project to a new folder on the desktop named "New Folder", the error disappeared, and I could run the project without any further issues. However, if I rename or move the project folder to another directory, the same error reappears. I tried to install the app using npm but didn't solve the problem, but for my colleague the app worked just with installing by npm. I don't know why it is working very randomly on any machine.

now my working structure is like this :
~/Desktop/New folder (3)/New-UI (develop)

Could anyone help me understand why this is happening and how to resolve it?

Comment: please provide a minimum reproducible example in your question so we can understand what is wrong and try to help you

Comment: thanks for commenting, actually I have no idea what code should I put here, because it is not because of the codes, since the same code one time works in one directory and doesn't on other one...